# Dialogflow does not evaluate parameters to its reference value

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have the following custom entity named 'department'. The entity defines like below:

department [Define synonyms - checked]:

appliances| stove, washer, appliance has, appliance part, appliances, appliances department.

An intent uses this entity type (department) in training phrases. ML is enabled for the corresponding intent.

The issue:
when in the DF console I enter 'appliances department', DF does not evaluate the value as 'appliances' and set it to be equals to original value (appliances department). If I use other synonyms, the value is evaluated correctly.

Could you please help me to resolve this case.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the entity, and it is working for me.

[image]

---

[image]

I believe that maybe Dialog Flow is seeing the synonym ‘appliances department’ as redundant since the value is ‘appliances’ and it is contained in the synonym list, as well.

Also, there is a possibility that the same value is being overlapped by other entities.